# How to compile this C code to WebAssembly correctly?

Tags: javascript, c, webassembly

I have the C code:

```
int edges_start[3000];
int edges_end[3000];
float edges_len[3000];

int g_links_id[1000][100];
float g_links_weight[1000][100];

int cache_id[1000];
float cache_distance[1000];
int cache_prev[1000];
int cache_links_id[1000][100];
float cache_links_weight[1000][100];

int queue_id[1000];
float queue_distance[1000];
int queue_prev[1000];
int queue_links_id[1000][100];
float queue_links_weight[1000][100];

void* memcpy(char* dst, char* src, int count) {
  while(count--) *dst++ = *src++;
}


void init_cpp() {
  for (int i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
    cache_id[i] = -2;
    queue_id[i] = -2;
    cache_distance[i] =  100000;
    queue_distance[i] = 100000;
    cache_prev[i] = -2;
    queue_prev[i] = -2;
    for (int j=0; j < 100; j++) {
      queue_links_id[i][j] = -2;
      queue_links_weight[i][j] = 100000;
      cache_links_id[i][j] = -2;
      cache_links_weight[i][j] = 100000;
    }
  }
}

void init_edges_cpp() {
  for (int i=0; i < 3000; i++) {
    edges_start[i] = -2;
    edges_end[i] = -2;
    edges_len[i] = -2.0;
  }

  for (int i=0; i < 1000; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < 100; j++) {
      g_links_id[i][j] = -2;
      g_links_weight[i][j] = -2.0;
    }
  }
}

void add_edge_cpp(int index, int start, int end, float len) {
  edges_start[index] = start;
  edges_end[index] = end;
  edges_len[index] = len;
}

void fill_graph_cpp() {
  for (int i=0; i < 3000; i++) {
    int s = edges_start[i];
    int e = edges_end[i];
    float len = edges_len[i];

    if (s == -2) {
      break;
    }

    int links_len = 0;

    for (int j=0; j < 100; j++) {
      if (g_links_id[s][j] == -2) {
        links_len = j;
        break;
      }
    }

    g_links_id[s][links_len] = e;
    g_links_weight[s][links_len] = len;

    for (int j=0; j < 100; j++) {
      if (g_links_id[e][j] == -2) {
        links_len = j;
        break;
      }
    }
    g_links_id[e][links_len] = s;
    g_links_weight[e][links_len] = len;
  }
}


void get_dists_cpp(int a, int L) {
  

    int i = L;
    while (--i >= 0) {
        
        
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            //console.log()
            if (g_links_id[i][j] == -2) {
                break;
            }
            cache_links_id[i][j] = g_links_id[i][j];
            cache_links_weight[i][j] = g_links_weight[i][j];
        }

        cache_id[i] = i;
    }


    queue_id[0] = cache_id[a];
    cache_distance[a] = 0;
    queue_distance[0] = cache_distance[a];
    queue_prev[0] = queue_prev[a];
    for (int j=0; j < 100; j++) {
        queue_links_id[0][j] = cache_links_id[a][j];
        queue_links_weight[0][j] = cache_links_weight[a][j];
    }
    
  
    
    i=0;
    int queue_len = 1;
    while (i < queue_len) {
        int node_id = queue_id[i];
        float node_distance = queue_distance[i];
        int node_prev = queue_prev[i];

        int j=0;
        for (int k=0; k < 100; k++) {
            if (queue_links_id[i][k] == -2) {
                j=k;
                break;
            }
        }

        while (--j >= 0) {
            int link_id = queue_links_id[i][j];
            float link_weight = queue_links_weight[i][j];

            int c_id = cache_id[link_id];
            float c_distance = cache_distance[link_id];
            int c_prev = cache_prev[link_id];

            float d = node_distance + link_weight;
            if (d < c_distance) {
                cache_prev[link_id] = node_id;
                cache_distance[link_id] = d;

                int last_ind = queue_len;
                queue_id[last_ind] = cache_id[link_id];
                queue_distance[last_ind] = cache_distance[link_id];

                for (int k=0; k < 100; k++) {
                    if (cache_links_id[link_id][k] == -2) {
                        break;
                    }
                    
            queue_links_id[last_ind][k] = cache_links_id[link_id][k];
            queue_links_weight[last_ind][k] = cache_links_weight[link_id][k];
          }
          queue_prev[last_ind] = cache_prev[link_id];
          queue_len++;
            }

        }
        i++;
    }

}

int get_edges_start(int index) {
  return edges_start[index];
}

float get_cache_distance(int index) {
    return cache_distance[index];
}

int get_cache_prev(int index) {
    return cache_prev[index];
}



int main() {
    init_edges_cpp();
    init_cpp();
    add_edge_cpp(0, 0, 2, 1);
    add_edge_cpp(1, 0, 1, 1);
    add_edge_cpp(2, 1, 2, 1);
    add_edge_cpp(3, 2, 3, 1);
    add_edge_cpp(4, 2, 4, 1);
    add_edge_cpp(5, 3, 4, 1);
    fill_graph_cpp();
    
    get_dists_cpp(0, 5);
    /*
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << i << " " << get_cache_distance(i) << " " << get_cache_prev(i) << endl;
    }
    */
    
    return 0;
}
```

It works correct, you can check it [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/yutiVBNOf)

But, when I tried to compile it to wasm with this [website](https://wasdk.github.io/WasmFiddle/)

I put in the left field this code: https://pastebin.com/NG10Z0jX
And in the right field that js code:

```
var wasmModule = new WebAssembly.Module(wasmCode);
var wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasmModule, wasmImports);
var wasm_module = wasmInstance.exports

wasm_module.main();

for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
  var c1 = wasm_module.get_cache_distance(i);
  var c2 = wasm_module.get_cache_prev(i);
  
  log(i+" " +c1 + " " + c2)
}
```

It returned wrong output:

```
vert: 0 dist: 0 prev -2
vert: 1 dist: 100000 prev -2
vert: 2 dist: 100000 prev -2
vert: 3 dist: 100000 prev -2
vert: 4 dist: 100000 prev -2
```

It should return this:

```
vert: 0 dist: 0.000000 prev: -2                                                                                                               
vert: 1 dist: 1.000000 prev: 0                                                                                                                
vert: 2 dist: 1.000000 prev: 0                                                                                                                
vert: 3 dist: 2.000000 prev: 2                                                                                                                
vert: 4 dist: 2.000000 prev: 2
```

**How to compile this C code to WebAssembly correctly?**

Comment: Why not use `struct`?

Comment: I want to compile code to wasm. As I know, you can't compile `struct` to wasm.

Comment: Structs are just a matter of memory layout... I don't see why you couldn't compile them to wasm.

Comment: Your code yields `Uncaught CompileError: WebAssembly.Module(): Compiling function #5:"get_dists_cpp" failed: not enough arguments on the stack for local.set, expected 1 more @+1273` in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to put this in C code:

```
void* memcpy(char* dst, char* src, int count) {
  void* p=dst;
  while(count--) *dst++ = *src++;
  return p;
}
```

Comment: Your original C code never calls `memcpy()`.

Comment: I need this function to compile this code to webassembly